# MySQL 1292 Warning on varchar date value to number conversion

Tags: mysql, warnings, mysql-error-1292

I know why the warning occurs.

On a varchar(20) column set to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' format in MySQL which a numeric comparison such as:

```
select * from table where varchar_date_column > 0;
```

is performed... Then I will have warnings that say:

```
Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2011-03-16 06:17:04' |
```

So my question is: Is there a reason NOT to do it this way?  Because it works in the program anyways.

Comment: Any reason to store date not in `datetime/timestamp`?

Comment: huh? date types can be indexed

Comment: @zerkms hi, yes I know this, I'm dealing with a decision that I didn't make. :3  If I remember correctly, it's the partial index on just the DATE() part of a datetime type that is wanted.

Comment: Index on datetime works pretty good. Varchar as date is truly bad idea. No comparison, bigger column size and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are storing a string, you should compare it to a string.

This should give you the same results, without the warning:

```
select * from table where varchar_date_column > '0';
```

Comment: Currently running a test on this. Will get back shortly.  :)

Comment: ACTUALLY... does not work.  Comparison does not work the same.  Exact same query gives row set result with 0 and an empty set with '0'.